# How to show an ImageField in Django template

Tags: django, django-models

I have looked this questions from the stack overflow.
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035290/django-show-imagefield)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846290/django-display-imagefield) about showing an image field in a template and follow accordingly. But the image is not showing in the template although the image is properly uploaded to the folder.

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
      book_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    book = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'books/books.html', context={'books': book})
```

template.html

```
<img class="group list-group-image" src="{{ books.book_thumbnail.url }}" width='240' alt="alt" />
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('books/', views.home),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: 1) you need to check that template shows correct url instead of {{ books.book_thumbnail.url }} when template is rendered. 2) you need to check that MEDIA_ROOT  shows to correct directory, there maybe problems with relative path

Comment: everything seems right

Comment: can you just show what url was actually rendered by {{ books.book_thumbnail.url }} and what do you see if you print MEDIA_ROOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printing media root works for me.

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
print(MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is what i just edited in settings.py